# "Hello world" code using Mesa 3D

Tags: c, 3d, mesa

Im looking for a "Hello world" code using Mesa 3D. Any help? I have found this code below, but since it is using `GL/glut.h` I think it corresponds to OpenGL but not Mesa 3D.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void displayMe(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(300, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello world :D");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayMe);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Mesa3d](http://www.mesa3d.org/intro.html) is an implementation of OpenGL. [GLUT](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) is a library on top of OpenGL, *which* implementation is used for OpenGL doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so that code is also ok for Mesa3d?

Comment: Yup, it ought to work fine.